# IIFE bundle with imported namespace as undefined

Tags: typescript, phaser-framework, rollupjs

I've this code:

```js
import * as Phaser from 'phaser';

new Phaser.Game({
    width:300,
    height:300,
    scale: {
        mode: Phaser.Scale.FIT,
    },
    type: Phaser.AUTO,
    scene: { create() {} },
});
```

When I compile and run it, I get this error at the bundle:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Phaser is not defined
```

**rollup.config.js**

```js
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default {
  input: 'src/EntryPoint.ts',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/EntryPoint.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
  ],
};
```

**index.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <script src="./dist/EntryPoint.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**package.json**

```json
{
  "name": "rollup-import-issue-mvc",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "start": "rollup -c && sirv --dev --max-age 0 --port 3000",
    "watch": "rollup -c -w",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-typescript": "^8.3.2",
    "phaser": "3.55.2",
    "rollup": "^2.72.1",
    "sirv-cli": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.6.4"
  }
}
```

MVC: https://github.com/Klaider/rollupjs-issue-0

This is what the bundle looks like:

```js
(function (Phaser) {
    'use strict';

    // ...

})(Phaser); // line where I get ReferenceError
```

**UPDATE**

Turns out I'm also getting:

```
(!) Unresolved dependencies
https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency
phaser (imported by src/EntryPoint.ts)
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
phaser (guessing 'Phaser')
```

However `phaser` is specified as a NPM dependence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find the answer in the [link](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#warning-treating-module-as-external-dependency) provided with the warning:

> **Warning: "Treating [module] as external dependency"**
>
> Rollup will only resolve relative module IDs by default. This means that an import statement like this…
>
> ```
> import moment from 'moment';
> ```
>
> …won't result in `moment` being included in your bundle – instead, it will be an external dependency that is required at runtime. If that's what you want, you can suppress this warning with the `external` option, which makes your intentions explicit:
>
> ```
> // rollup.config.js  
> export default {  
>  entry: 'src/index.js',  
>  dest: 'bundle.js',  
>  format: 'cjs',  
>  external: ['moment'] // <-- suppresses the warning  
> };
> ```
>
> If you do want to include the module in your bundle, you need to tell Rollup how to find it. In most cases, this is a question of using [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve).
>
> Some modules, like `events` or `util`, are built in to Node.js. If you want to include those (for example, so that your bundle runs in the browser), you may need to include [rollup-plugin-polyfill-node](https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node).

So in your case you have to use [@rollup/plugin-node-resolve](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve):

```
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';
import { nodeResolve } from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
  input: 'src/EntryPoint.ts',
  output: {
    file: 'dist/EntryPoint.js',
    format: 'iife',
  },
  plugins: [
    typescript(),
    nodeResolve()
  ],
};
```

NB: maybe you need to use [@rollup/plugin-commonjs](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/commonjsps) as stated [here](https://github.com/rollup/plugins/tree/master/packages/node-resolve#using-with-rollupplugin-commonjs)